# Javascript detect popup window close

Tags: javascript, popup

I have this code in my popup window (which is opened by parent window):

```
window.onbeforeunload = closeWindow;
function closeWindow(){

}
```

The problem is that this code fires when parent window is being refreshed. Is there a way for this code only to fire when popup window is actually being closed?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. You could try something like this in the window that opens the popup.

```
var NewWin = window.open("NewWin", "example.htm", "width=100;height=300;");
// modify styling as necessary etc.
NewWin.onbeforeunload = function() {
window.setTimeout(function() {
if (!NewWin) {
// window has been closed
} else {
// false alarm, just a refresh
}
}, 1000);
}
```

EDIT: To prevent the window from reopening on parent page refresh, use a similar technique from within the popup

```
window.opener.onload = function() {
window.opener.NewWin = self;
}
```

Then change the first line of the code above to:

```
document.onload = function() {
if (!NewWin) { var NewWin = window.open("NewWin", "example.htm", "width=100;height=300;"); }
}
```

Comment: parent window will open popup. then if code in parent window is refreshed, then it means code will ran again and open popup again. this is not suppose to happen! popup needs to stay opened without parent window re-opening it again on parent window refresh.